# Пояснительные члены предложения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

В конце 16 века сюда(,)в почетную ссылку(,) был отправлен царевич Дмитрий — младший сын Ивана Грозного.

Вопрос. Является ли словосочетание «в почетную ссылку» пояснительным членом? Лично у меня не вызывает сомнения, что это пояснительный член. Но со мной не согласны.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что это предложение из ЕГЭ (см. [здесь](https://izilearn.ru/index.php?r=egerus2020%2Fview&id=99) и [здесь](https://studarium.ru/question/6659)):
*В конце XVI века сюда, в почётную ссылку, был отправлен царевич Димитрий — младший сын Ивана Грозного.*

Царевич Дмитрий (Димитрий) вместе с матерью, Марией Нагой, находился в ссылке в Угличе.
Я склоняюсь к тому, что в этом предложении "в почётную ссылку" (отправлен *куда?*) является ***уточняющим** обстоятельством места*.
Теоретически можно обойтись и без запятых (допустим, если бы в тексте уже имелось упоминание о высылке).
Вот похожее предложение (без обособления; в предыдущем контексте есть информация об удалении царицы с сыном в город Углич):

> Пока все это происходило в Москве, Мария Нагая с сыном и со своей родней продолжала жить в Угличе в почетной ссылке.
> [С. Ф. Платонов. Полный курс лекций по русской истории](http://www.spsl.nsc.ru/history/platon/var2/chart2-3.html)

[Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_22.htm)

P. S. В тестах перед "пишут историки" пропущено тире, о котором, собственно, и речь.

> «Церемония открытия первого народного представительства началась в 10 часов утра торжественным молебном во всех церквах обеих столиц. День, по свидетельству современников, был жаркий. На всякий случай развели Николаевский и Дворцовый мосты», — пишут историки.

Comment: Конечно, можно обойтись и без запятых. И да, вопрос из ЕГЭ.

Comment: Кстати, по первой ссылке в ответах ошибка.

Comment: Если это уточняющее обстоятельство, то должно быть сужение понятия. Т.е.  переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому. На мой взгляд, здесь нет такого значения.

Comment: О-и... Я не рассматривала ответы. У Розенталя: Но бывают случаи, когда уточняющий член по выражаемому им понятию шире, чем уточняемый: _Я лежал на кровати, **в незнакомой горнице**, и чувствовал большую слабость_ (П.)... У нас же "сюда" = в Углич.

Comment: Рима Михайлова,  да, бывают и такие моменты. Но я не уверен, что этот случай можно подвести под наш.

Answer (score 1):

С одной стороны, можно рассматривать как обстоятельство цели/причины, следующее за обстоятельством места, и вроде как обособлять не нужно, тем более при перемене мест даже вопроса не возникает: отправлен в ссылку в Михайловское, отправлен в ссылку на Кавказ... Но с другой стороны, при таком порядке слов, да и с определением в придачу, "в почетную ссылку" похоже на дополнительные сведения, поэтому я бы обособила. Для меня это похоже на обороты с предлогами "в связи с..." и т.п.

Comment: Согласен с вами. Не то что похоже, а здесь носит пояснительный характер.